# Mysterious white space (margin) beneath revolution slider (Wordpress related)

Tags: css, wordpress, slider

I've been using CSS Viewer Chrome Extension and adding and removing margin-bottom:-50px; or margin-top:-50px; from different styles trying to find the magic spot that's creating this white space beneath the slider but I cannot figure it out. I've spent a few hours on this trying to make it go away but it's still persists... Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Link: http://104.236.223.60/

Comment: did you try right-cliccking the spot and selecting "inspect element"?

Comment: ummm... what white space and what slider? I do not see any white space. also what browser are you using?

Comment: screenshot: http://prntscr.com/7htrhf    Chrome browser, yes I've used inspect element as well.

Comment: Nothing guys? Anything I can do to help answer my own question? Really stumped here...